# If a matrix acts injectively on a module can we find a coordinate projection which maintains injectivity?

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a module over $R$ (we may assume wlog that $R$ is noetherian and $M$ is finite and nonzero). Say we have a matrix $A \in M_{n\times m}(R)$ such that the induced map $$M^m \cong M \otimes R^m \overset{\mathrm{id}_M \otimes A}{\to} M \otimes R^n \cong M^n$$
is injective. This implies $m \leq n$ (in the Noetherian case you can see this by taking $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{Ass}(M)$ and restricting the map above along an inclusion $R/\mathfrak{p} \hookrightarrow M$, then localizing at $\mathfrak{p}$ so that it's linear algebra over a field).

Can we find some coordinate projection $M^n \to M^m$ such that the composition $M^m \to M^n \to M^m$ is still injective?  In other words, can we drop $n-m$ rows of $A$ while maintaining injectivity of its action on $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the ring $R = k[x,y]$ and $M = k[x,y]/(xy)$. Consider the map $M \to M^2$ given by $t\mapsto (tx,ty)$. This is injective, but will not remain injective after any coordinate projection.